# String and Variable combination

Tags: c++, string, qt, qmessagebox, const-char

i m a beginner in c++ and i have a question.
how can i combine a variable and a string in the folowing line.

```
QMessageBox::Question(this,"Report", "the Report is in Path: "  + pdfPath + "saved, do you want to open it", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

`pdfPath`is my Variable where the path of my pdf-file is saved.

I tried this, ("the Report is in Path: "  + pdfPath + "saved, do you want to open it") but it does not work.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: o invalid operands to binary expression (const Char[] and char[])
that is the error

Comment: The problem is that `"the Report is in Path: "` is not a `QString` and it cannot be concantenated with `pdfPath`. You might want to do something like this instead: `QString("the Report is in Path:  %1 saved, do you want to open it").arg(pdfPath)`.

Comment: You might even go: `tr("the Report is in Path: %1 saved, do you want to open it", pdfPath)` to handle translation.

Answer (score 1):

if pdf path is not a QString then you can to convert it into one,

```
//
std::string pdfPath="C:\here!";
QMessageBox::question(this, "Report", "The Report is in Path: "  + QString::fromStdString(pdfPath) + "saved, do you want to open it", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
//
```

concatenating QStrings works straigh forward cos the operator + is overloaded

```
QString pdfPath="C:\here!";
QMessageBox::question(this, "Report", "The Report is in Path: "  + pdfPath + "saved, do you want to open it", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```